# Question about Linq to xml from a tutorial I am following

Tags: xml, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, linq-to-xml

I am following  [this tutorial](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/03/08/a-simple-way-to-programmatically-create-sharepoint-security-groups.aspx)

```
var groups = from sharePointGroup in groupsXml.Root.Elements("Group")

                select new

                {

                    Name = sharePointGroup.Attribute("Name").Value,

                    Owner = sharePointGroup.Attributes("Owner").Any() ? sharePointGroup.Attribute("Owner").Value : null,

                    Description = sharePointGroup.Attributes("Description").Any() ? sharePointGroup.Attribute("Description").Value : string.Empty,

                    PermissionLevel = sharePointGroup.Attributes("PermissionLevel").Any() ? sharePointGroup.Attribute("PermissionLevel").Value : null,

                    Users = sharePointGroup.Elements("User").Any() ? sharePointGroup.Elements("User") : null

                };
```

They have this: `groupsXml.Root.Elements("Group")` but when I try to do this I get an error

> Error 3   Could not find an
>   implementation of the query pattern
>   for source type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   'Select' not found.  Are you missing a
>   reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a
>   using directive for 'System.Linq'

When I look at my references I can't see System.Linq(only System.Xml.Linq; and SharePoint.linq)

When I look up on  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) I see that it takes in a "Xname" instead of a string

Comment: Have you got a using statement at the top of your class file for System.Linq?
using System.Linq;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Xname has a constructor that takes a string, so this is correct.
2. If you have no `using System.Linq;`, you need to add it.
3. You don't need to add any reference to your project. The namespace `System.Linq` is defined in the System.Core.dll assembly, which is referenced by default.

Comment: Don't worry had to wait till I was allowed to mark a answer as "the answer"